# Password Validation With C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am building a password validation program in Qt with C++, but I'm running into some issues making it work properly with Qt.

Apparently Qt doesn't use the `isalpha` function, so I'm not able to tell if a character is alpha.  Using it results in the error `No matching function for call to 'isalpha'` I haven't been able to find a good replacement for this.

I'm also getting the error `No matching member function for call to 'isUpper' and 'isDigit'` even though `isUpper` is supposed to be supported by Qt, unlike `isalpha`.

I am trying to port over code that worked perfectly in pure C++.  This is that code:

```
int i;
char password[30];
int lower, upper, number, symbol;
lower = upper = number = symbol = 0;

cout << "Enter your password" << endl;
cin >> password;

int len = strlen(password);

for (i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    if(isalpha(password[i]))
    {
        if(isupper(password[i]))
        {
            upper++;
        }
        else
        {
            lower++;
        }
    }
    else if(isdigit(password[i]))
    {
        number++;
    }
    else
    {
        symbol++;
    }
}

if (upper >= 1 && lower >= 1 && number >= 1 && symbol >= 1 && len >=6)
{
    printf("Your password is good!");
}
if (upper < 1)
{
    printf("You need an uppercase letter \n");
}
if (lower < 1)
{
    printf("You need a lowercase letter \n");
}
if (number < 1)
{
    printf("You need a number \n");
}
if (symbol < 1)
{
    printf("You need a symbol \n");
}
if (len < 6)
{
    printf("Your password must be at least 6 characters \n");
}
```

The way I have it set up in Qt is almost identical, but I can't get it to run without the errors with `is alpha` and `isUpper` errors:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QWidget>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int i;
    QString username = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QString password = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
    int usernameLen = ui->lineEdit->text().length();
    int passwordLen = ui->lineEdit_2->text().length();
    // QLabel valLabel = ui->label_5;
    QString valMsg = ui->label_5->text();
    int upper;
    int lower;
    int digit;
    int symbol;

    if(usernameLen < 8)
    {
        ui->label_5->setText("Your username must be at least 8 characters\n");
    }
    if(passwordLen < 8)
    {
        ui->label_5->setText(valMsg + "Your password must be at least 8 characters\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i<usernameLen; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(username[i]))
        {
            if(QChar::isUpper(username[i]))
            {
                upper++;
            }
            else
            {
                lower++;
            }
        }
        else if (QChar::isDigit(username[i]))
        {
            digit++;
        }
        else
        {
            symbol++;
        }
    }
    if (upper >= 1 and lower >= 1 and digit >= 1 and symbol >= 1 and usernameLen >=6)
    {
        ui->label_5->setText(valMsg + username + "Your password is good");
    }
    if (upper < 1)
    {
        ui->label_5->setText(valMsg + username + "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter\n");
    }
    if (lower < 1)
    {
        ui->label_5->setText(valMsg + username + "Password must contain at least one lowercase letter\n");
    }
    if (digit < 1)
    {
        ui->label_5->setText(valMsg + username + "Password must contain at least one number\n");
    }
    if (symbol < 1)
    {
        ui->label_5->setText(valMsg + username + "Password must contain at least one symbol\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: QChar::isLetter is for isalpha. What kind of errors you get?

Comment: isalpha is a part of C runtime library. That is strange that you cannot link with it. My guess is that username[idx] is not exactly C char type? Or QChar from which you need to get that char or maybe use 'wide' version of isalpha.

Comment: The static versions of QChar::isUpper(), QChar::isDigit(), etc. are only intended for UTF-32 character types, not UTF-16.

Comment: I changed it to `Char:isLetter` so thats a start, but now everything I'm using in QChar (`isDigit`,`isLetter`, and `isUpper`) are coming backing with that same error `No matching member function for call to 'isUpper'` or `isLetter` etc.

Comment: It also says this for each of the three errors:

`candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'QCharRef' to 'uint' (aka 'unsigned int') for 1st argument`

    inline bool QChar::isLetter(uint ucs4)
                                 ^

Comment: MrEricSir, what would the implications of a difference in character type be, and how would I address that?

Comment: Ignore the static functions, use the non-static members:`QChar::isUpper(username[i])` becomes `username[i].isUpper()`.

Comment: Frank,  that was the right answer, if you post it, ill check it off as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
// ...

QString userName = "UserName1";
for ( const auto& character : userName )
{
    if ( character.isUpper() )
    {
        upper++;
    }
    else if ( character.isLower() )
    {
        lower++;
    }
    else if ( character.isDigit() )
    {
        digit++;
    }
    else
    {
        symbol++;
    }
}

// ...
```

And something similar for the password.